# Is there a way to initialise JS SDK For Every AJAX Page Load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Similar to this question: [FB.api only loads on first AJAX call to page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11184031/fb-api-only-loads-on-first-ajax-call-to-page)

Due to the structure of my site, pages are loaded via AJAX. Everything works fine except the second time the page with the `window.fbAsyncInit` function on it is loaded, it doesn't work. There are no errors shown on the console, all that is shown is my `auth-loggedout` div contents with the facebook login button inside it but clicks to it are unresponsive.

I know for certain that I am logged in since on the previous page load I just used the api to post to my wall.

Is there a way to change the initialisation so that it will work on every page load?

```
// Init the SDK upon load
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo $appID; ?>', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//domain.co.uk/myoe/channel.html', // Path to your Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });


    // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
        // lots of code
    }; 

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
   (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, managed to solve it eventually:

```
if (typeof FB !== 'undefined') {
    // your code from  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // but WITHOUT FB.init({...});
}
```

so if you put the common code in a function you could then call the function from both so you are not repeating yourself.

Quite a straightforward answer to a really frustrating problem.